# Print Message Once Every Million Iterations

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

I need to write a loop that prints out a message once every million iterations. I want to let it run for 10 seconds (clock time) to see how many statements get printed.

I think I've just tied myself in knots now though...

```
public class OneInAMillion{
  public static void main(String []args){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  //time at start of execution
    long endTime = startTime + 10000;  //time at end of execution (10000 = 10 seconds)
    int count = 1;

    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) { //run this before 10 seconds is up
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(i % 1000000 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Iteration: " + count++);  //print every millionth iteration
        }
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Time up!"); //print once loop finishes
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Is there a error, or is it just not working?  What have you tried?

Comment: You can use only while loop and increment i inside.

Answer (score 5):

You have a loop in the loop. Think about what each loop does - the first one will go on until there has passed 10 seconds. The other one will simply start going from 0 to 1, and at the next iteration of the while-loop, it will go from 0 to 2, then 0 to 3 and so on. It will also print when it's at 0 (so a lot) because 0%1000000 is 0.

Try combining them into one single loop. This can be done by getting rid of the while-loop and only having the for-loop with the conditions of the while-loop, as such:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;  //time at end of execution (10000 = 10 seconds)
     for (int i = 1; System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime; i++) {
        if(i % 1000000 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Iteration: " + i/1000000);  //print every millionth iteration
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Time up!"); //print once loop finishes
  }
```

Note that `count` will always be i/1000000, so I got rid of it.

Comment: This seems to be the most logical reasoning so far but it still doesn't print the "Time's up!" message and I get vastly different results each time I run the code.

Comment: @samwhocan Just replace this with your while-loop and what's inside it, not the code after or before and it'll work =)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions so far. Still not working though... Prints "Error!" many times!

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endTime = startTime + 10000;
    int count = 1;
    
    for (int i = 1; System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime; i++) {
    if(i % 1000000 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Iteration: " + count++);
    } else { System.out.println("Error!");
    }

Comment: Think about it. Every time i % 1000000 is not true (which it is every time it iterates a part from when it is 1000000, 2000000, 3000000 etc), it will go to the else clause. Every time it goes to the else-clause it will print "Error!", as you defined it that way, of course. Just remove the else-clause and error-print.

Comment: Ok fair enough. I see my error there, but now it is just the same as before as it prints out "Iteration: n" a random amount of times and fails to ever get to the "Time up!" message which confirms the end of 10 seconds.

Comment: @samwhocan Edited the post with the entire main-function, enhanced.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but there's still no "Time up!" message and it's always a random amount of print outs.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your `for` loop, do `i++` before your `if` and print `i` instead of count and you should be set.

```
public class OneInAMillion{
  public static void main(String []args){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  //time at start of execution
    long endTime = startTime + 10000;  //time at end of execution (10000 = 10 seconds)
    //int count = 1;
    int i = 0;
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) { //run this before 10 seconds is up
        i++;
        if(i % 1000000 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Iteration: " + i);  //print every millionth iteration
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Time up!"); //print once loop finishes
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer would have been infinitely better with a code sample.

Answer (score -1):

Your for loop exit condition is interfering with your while loop exit condition and preventing it from being evaluated when you expect. Get rid of the while loop:

```
public class OneInAMillion{
  public static void main(String []args){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  //time at start of execution
    long endTime = startTime + 10000;  //time at end of execution (10000 = 10 seconds)
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= endTime) {
        break;
      }

      if(i % 1000000 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Iteration: " + count++);  //print every millionth iteration
      }
    }


    System.out.println("Time up!"); //print once loop finishes
  }
}
```

Comment: Your entire for-loop is equivalent to the if-statement (0 % 1000000 == 0). It will only iterate once, this is not what OP wants.

Comment: Aye, I had the wrong exit condition for the for loop; your answer is what I was aiming for. :}